# Co-petition with PerlMonks?

Tags: discussion, policy, cross-posting, external-sources

What is the ideal stance to take with regard to other similar resources, such as [PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/)?

Comment: What is co-petition?

Answer (score 3):

1. Quote and link to source
2. Name the author of the source if you can
3. This should apply to all quotes, not just those from a similar site
4. If duplication of content isn't allowed, either find a different source or settle for just a link

Answer (score 3):

Speaking from the point of view of a perlmonks user, and assuming you are being literal in "co-petition", we generally prefer to know where else you asked the question, so we don't end up repeating ourselves (or somebody else).

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste good answers, with attribution, license allowing.

Answer (score 0):

Like any other source of information, you can quote the source, but be sure to link to original URL.

Answer (score 0):

The more the merrier.  There's going to be some overlap of users (something would be very wrong if there were not), but I suspect there'll be a lot more non-overlap.

(Also speaking as a perlmonks user, and not to set policy - it's early days yet.)